How to remove everything in a string before first occurrence of pattern (Python)
I have a string that looks like the following:
sample_string = 'Hello, my name is Bob.\nI like sparkling water.\nMy favorite flavor is mango.\n Goodbye.'

I want to do two things:

Edit the string in a way that removes all characters before the first occurrence of '\n'
Remove all occurrences of '\n'

I've got #2 sorted out just fine:
sample_string.replace('\n',' ')

But, I'm not sure how to structure a regex expression to pinpoint the first \n and remove all characters before it.
The final string should look like:
final_string = 'I like sparkling water. My favorite flavor is mango. Goodbye.'


There are exactly three reasonable ways to do this: you can make the regex match the part you want to remove; or you can find out where the regex matched and trim the string to that point; or you can take a non-regex-based approach to removing the first line. Every one of these is a duplicate.

You could use e.g. sample_string = re.sub(r'(?:^.*)?\n *', ' ', sample_string).strip() See regex101 for explanation.

How would I adapt this for a pandas dataframe?

You can split on the \n first to divide your sentence up:
sample_string = 'Hello, my name is Bob.\nI like sparkling water.\nMy favorite flavor is mango.\n Goodbye.'
sample_string_split = sample_string.split('\n', 1)[1]

Keep in mind the [1] will fail if there is no \n in the string - check accordingly.
Then replace
print(sample_string_split.replace('\n', ' '))


How would I modify this for a pandas dataframe?
